# Two entries for each disk on hba

Tags: ubuntu, disk

I see two device entries (ie. /dev/sdaa and /dev/sdab ) for each disk in my Quanta M4600H.

The HBA is an LSI SAS2308. I assume this is happening because of the two SAS connectors the HBA utilizes.

Is there a way to show which two device entries belong to the same physical disk?

I've tried all options in lsblk without success.

None of the disks are mounted so far

OS: Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS

Thanks in advance

EDIT1

Output of lsblk: https://pastebin.com/7tHP4KJ6

Comment: Have you check the minor number of device?

Comment: I tried to make sense out of the minor number but I can't find a pattern.
I'll add the output

Comment: Please put complete output of `dmesg` after boot into pastebin, and edit question with link.